# Generate random sequence of AlphaNumeric

Tags: c#

I want a code to generate sequence of Alphanumeric character like LLNNLLNNLL where L is the Letter and N is the number. For example if the length is 5 the sequence will be LLNNL and if the length is 6 the sequence will be LLNNLL and if 7 it would be LLNNLLN.

```
string alphabets = "ABCDEFGHIJKLMNPQRSTUVWX";
int length = model.VALUE_INT;
string result = "";
for (int i = 0; i < length; i++)
{
    int next = _random.Next(23);
    result += alphabets.ElementAt(next);
    result += _randomNum.Next(1, 9);
}
```

This is what I have tried but condition is not fulfilling

Comment: Please also note that I am using Random() library to generate Letter and Number

Comment: This kind of question is usually not allowed on StackOverflow. You are required to explain what you tried, and what's the nature of the problem. StackOverflow is not a "please do my homework" site. Just to give you a direction, you could try to use two alphabets, one for "L" letters and one for "N", and with a "for" loop generate the required number of random chars.

Comment: Just to be clear, L and N are not letters or anything. L can be random character and N can be random integer. BTW it's not my homework, I want to generate a unique code every time when it goes to the loop. I tried many things but it did not worked, shared the picture as well. Lastly sequence should be what I have mentioned above...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For each position (value of `i`) of your output string you need to check if you need a character or an integer.
Since the pattern repeats every 4 positions, you can achieve this using the modulo operator:

```
for (int i = 0; i < length; i++)
{
    switch (i % 4)
    {
        case 0:
        case 1:
            int next = _random.Next(23);
            result += alphabets.ElementAt(next);
            break;

        case 2:
        case 3:
            result += _randomNum.Next(1, 9);
            break;
    }
}
```

Or another possibility: Add blocks of LLNN and then truncate the result to the needed length...

```
for (int i = 0; i <= (length/4); i++)
{
    result += alphabets.ElementAt(_random.Next(23));
    result += alphabets.ElementAt(_random.Next(23));
    result += _randomNum.Next(1, 9); 
    result += _randomNum.Next(1, 9); 
}
result = result.Substring(0,length);
```

If you want to improve these lines, you can use a `StringBuilder`

Comment: Thank, it worked for me the last piece of code you added